# Bootstrap form comment section forcing rows to move

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a basic horizontal form written in Angular that uses bootstrap components. My problem is that there is a "Comment field" that pushes down the fields the next column over. I thought my problem might be in nesting `<div>` tags but I cleaned it up and this is still happening.

I thought of splitting up the form into two sections, the first two columns and the last two, but then I'm worried about complicating it and also ruining the tabbing capabilities.

This is the code for the comment section.

```
<label for="comment" class="col-md-1 control-label">Tenth Comment:</label>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <textarea class="form-control input-sm" rows="8" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
```

[image]

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mkfwaagd/

Comment: It can't not do that as it's on the next row - bootstrap works in rows

Answer (score 0):

You could put the IsMessedUp Date and Eleventh Thing within the same column that has it's own 2 rows

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">...text area...</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <!--Eleventh-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cool-md-12">
                <!--IsMessedUp Date-->
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```